# Cannot solve symbol 'Editor'

Tags: java, android

Normally a "Invalidate cache and restart" fix the problem, "Rebuilding the project", "restart the program" or "restarting the computer" works but it seems like it's not synced with my project or something.

In my Mainactivity I'm able to use Editor without any problems but with my other class (in the same folder) I can't use the same editor method as before.

Here is a few lines of my code

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.carl.gps.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    float totalDistanceInMeters = sharedPreferences.getFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", 0f);

    boolean firstTimeGettingPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", true);


    if (firstTimeGettingPosition) {
        editor.putBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", false);
    } else {
        Location previousLocation = new Location("");
        previousLocation.setLatitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLatitude", 0f));
        previousLocation.setLongitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLongitude", 0f));

        float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
        totalDistanceInMeters += distance;
        editor.putFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", totalDistanceInMeters);
    }
```

Another problem I had was making a permission for this line:

```
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
```

I have already declared permissions like:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

which should be enough in my opinion but I'm kind of new to Android Studio so maybe I'm wrong.

This is my dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

}

Would be very grateful for any help around about this errors I get.

Comment: use `SharedPreferences.Editor` instead of `sharedPreferences.Editor`

Comment: Thanks! Still doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Found the solution! Sorry for your time :) forgot Editor editor

Answer (score 1):

yeah it will throw you error "cannot resolve Editor" because you have to written  `sharedPreferences.Editor` instead of that write this `SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();` hope it will solve ur problem